# Jenkins call to mount_smbfs fails with Authentication error

Tags: macos, jenkins, mount, samba

I am running Jenkins on Mac OS X 10.7.5 and have it handle nightly backup to a SMB share on a Windows server. I want to mount the SMB drive automatically as part of the backup script but mount_smbfs fails from within Jenkins. The mount command I use is of the form:

```
mount_smbfs "//WORKGROUP;user:password@server/share" /Users/user/share
```

This works fine from the Terminal command line but in Jenkins gives me the error:

```
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
```

I have made sure that Jenkins runs the command as the same user as on the command line and nothing stood out in the differences in the PATH and other environment variables.

Comment: The relevant apple info at support.apple.com/kb/HT1568 unfortunately does not have a pointer to a bugreport and changerequest database (which most monopolist like Apple, Samsung and Microsoft seem to find a bad idea). Hopefully Mac OS 10.9 will have a better SAMBA implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer yet - just a list of information relevant for the diagnosis. Please edit this answer if you find any proper therapy.

Here are some relevant Apple support articles:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1568
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4829

and these are the man pages

- man mount_smbfs
- man smbutil
- man nsmb.conf

You might want to try out
smbutil view "/WORKGROUP;user:password@server"

to check the availabilty of the server.

the -N option of the mount_smbfs command is good for automating the login process

```
   -N      Do not ask for a password.  At run time, mount_smbfs reads the
             ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf file for additional configuration parameters
             and a password.  If no password is found, mount_smbfs prompts for it.
```

There is also the question of plaintext or encrypted passwords addressed at:

- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050506120948120

Comment: The root of the problems is that apple tried to reimplement samba and made quite a few mistakes while doing so : http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/03/23/inside_mac_os_x_10_7_lion_server_apple_replaces_samba_for_windows_networking_services